# Verifying all values of array are found in a hash of selected keys

Tags: ruby

If a User has a set of roles attached to them and each role has a set of scopes, how can I check if the User has all the scopes

For example, I have a mapping of roles to scopes

```
scopes_for_roles = {
  artist: ['draw', 'sing'],
  teacher: ['read', 'write'],
  athlete: ['draw', 'read', 'dance']
}
```

For `User_A` who has roles `athlete` and `teacher`, how can I check (`return T/F`) if he/she has the following scopes?

```
  scopes = ['read', 'write'] --> TRUE
  scopes = ['sing', 'read', 'write', 'dance'] --> FALSE    # Missing sing
```

What I've tried is the below

```
roles.product(scopes).select { |role, scope| scopes_for_roles[role].include?(scope) if scopes_for_roles.key?(role) }.size >= scopes.size
```

However, I believe the snippet above has a bug where it only checks the `.size` of the selected permutations and not the actual scopes themselves. So if a User has the roles `teacher` and `athlete`, the snippet will return `true` for scopes `['read', 'sing']` because `'read'` is found TWICE in roles `teacher` and `athlete`.

Note: I could have several for loops w/ key-value checks but I was wondering if there was a cleaner/shorter approach like the snippet I provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the duplicate scopes are a problem when you are relying on counting. To continue with that approach you will need to apply `Array#uniq` to remove duplicates at some point. (Also, `includes_code?` is not a Ruby method.) I suggest that you abandon the counting approach. First extract the relevant scopes from `scopes_for_roles`:

```
roles = [:athlete, :teacher]
scopes = ['read', 'write']
```

```
a = scopes_for_roles.values_at(*roles)
  #=> [["draw", "read", "dance"], ["read", "write"]]
```

See [Hash#values_at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at).

At this point you have several choices. Perhaps the easiest is to first flatten `a`:

```
b = a.flatten
  #=> ["draw", "read", "dance", "read", "write"]
```

Then execute one of the following:

```
scopes.all? { |s| b.include?(s) }
  #=> true

(scopes - b).empty?
  #=> true (scopes - b #=> [])

scopes & b == scopes
  #=> true (scopes & b #=> ['write', 'dance'])
```

See [Array#-](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-2D) and [Array#&](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-26).

Instead of `flatten` you could use

```
b = a.reduce(:+)
  #=> ["draw", "read", "dance", "read", "write"]
```

or

```
b = a.reduce(:|)
  #=> ["draw", "read", "dance", "write"]
```

See [Array#|](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-7C).

If

```
scopes = ['sing', 'read', 'write', 'dance']
```

then

```
scopes.all? { |s| b.include?(s) }
  #=> false

(scopes - b).empty?
  #=> false (scopes - b #=> ['sing'])

scopes & b == scopes
  #=> false (scopes & b #=> ['read', 'write', 'dance'])
```

---

I suggest the following.

```
def have_em_all?(scopes_for_roles, roles, scopes)
  (scopes - scopes_for_roles.values_at(*roles).reduce(:|)).empty?
end
```

```
roles = [:athlete, :teacher]
scopes1 = ['read', 'write']
scopes2 = ['sing', 'read', 'write', 'dance']
```

```
have_em_all?(scopes_for_roles, roles, scopes1) #=> true
have_em_all?(scopes_for_roles, roles, scopes2) #=> false
```

For the first example the steps are as follows.

```
a = scopes_for_roles.values_at(*roles)
  #=> [["draw", "read", "dance"], ["read", "write"]]
```

```
b = a.reduce(:|)
  #=> ["draw", "read", "dance", "write"]
```

```
c = scopes1 - b
  #=> []
c.empty?
  #=> true
```

In the second example we would obtain

```
c = scopes2 - b
  #=> ["sing"]
c.empty?
  #=> false
```

Comment: This is by far one of best answers I have ever received. It might actually be THE best :). Thanks for the multiple examples and approaches. Also, thank you for providing useful links to documentation. Lastly, THANK YOU for leading by example on what a wonderful, thoughtful, and elegant Stackoverflow answer should be!

Comment: Aw shucks, just glad to be of help.